# problem in verification code of google drive api

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am working on a application that uploads and shows file from google drive to a website and for that i am using google drive api in php and i have followed the quickstart.php when i enter the verification code it shows me some error

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, null given in D:\xampp\htdocs\google-drive-api\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:67
> Stack trace:
> #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\google-drive-api\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(67): count()
> #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\google-drive-api\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(141): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory->release()
> #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\google-drive-api\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(103): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError()
> #3 D:\xampp\htdocs\google-drive-api\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlHandler.php(43): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish()
> #4 D:\xampp\htdocs\google-drive-api\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\Proxy.php(28): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler->__invoke()
> #5 D:\xampp\htdocs\google-drive-api\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\Proxy.php(51): GuzzleHttp\Handler\Proxy::GuzzleHttp\Handler{closure}()
> #6 D:\xampp\htdocs\google-drive-api\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\PrepareBodyMiddleware.php(72): GuzzleHttp\Handler\Proxy::GuzzleHttp\Handler{closure}()
> #7 D:\xampp\htdocs\google-drive-api\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Middleware.php(30): GuzzleHttp\PrepareBodyMiddleware->__invoke()
> #8 D:\xampp\htdocs\google-drive-api\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\RedirectMiddleware.php(68): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp{closure}()
> #9 D:\xampp\htdocs\google-drive-api\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Middleware.php(57): GuzzleHttp\RedirectMiddleware->__invoke()
> #10 D:\xampp\htdocs\google-drive-api\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\HandlerStack.php(67): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp{closure}()
> #11 D:\xampp\htdocs\google-drive-api\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php(268): GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack->__invoke()
> #12 D:\xampp\htdocs\google-drive-api\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php(96): GuzzleHttp\Client->transfer()
> #13 D:\xampp\htdocs\google-drive-api\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php(104): GuzzleHttp\Client->sendAsync()
> #14 D:\xampp\htdocs\google-drive-api\vendor\google\auth\src\HttpHandler\Guzzle6HttpHandler.php(34): GuzzleHttp\Client->send()
> #15 D:\xampp\htdocs\google-drive-api\vendor\google\auth\src\OAuth2.php(492): Google\Auth\HttpHandle#16 D:\xampp\htdocs\google-drive-api\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php(184): Google\Auth\OAuth2->fetchAuthToken()
> #17 D:\xampp\htdocs\google-drive-api\google-drive.php(52): Google_Client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode()
> #18 D:\xampp\htdocs\google-drive-api\google-drive.php(70): getClient()
> #19 {main}
> thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\google-drive-api\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 67

Comment: Please edit your question and include you code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of PHP 7.2, the `count()` function will throw a warning when a value passed into it is not countable. Later on, this was made to throw a fatal error in PHP 8.0

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

> **Changelog**
>
> | Version | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | PHP 7.2 | `count()` will now yield a warning on invalid countable types passed to the value parameter. |

---

Since PHP 8.0 is a relatively new (and major) release that [just came out 4 months ago in November](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php), there is a good chance that a very large portion of PHP libraries aren't up to date yet. (I'm still developing in PHP 7.4 because of this.)

Assuming you're using the [google/apiclient](https://packagist.org/packages/google/apiclient) package, you should be good to go now as it seems to have been updated to support PHP 8.0 on Jan 19th in v2.9.0 (almost a month after you asked this question).

Edit: This is all based on the assumption you're running PHP 8.0, as this is the only version of PHP that throws a fatal error when passing a non countable variable into `count()`.

Answer (score 0):

Must be a problem with the php version . I was on php8 and was facing the same issue but when once I change to php7.3 the error became warning. Since the major changes in php7.4 and greater that might be causing the error of count()